# How to show uI-select(angularjs) when, click on html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want to show UI-select drop-down when, we click on html-element. Please see the demo [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/UGxmVynROpvkZmamKfI5?p=preview). In Demo we are showing three elements, when we select any of elements it must show related `ui-select(angularjs)`. How I will do this...

```
<div class="wrapper col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <a title="week? category"  class="tag" ng-class="{selected:selectedType == 'week'}" ng-click="makeActive('week')">week</a>
    <a title="week? category"  class="tag" ng-class="{selected:selectedType == 'month'}" ng-click="makeActive('month')">month</a>
    <a title="week? category"  class="tag" ng-class="{selected:selectedType == 'year'}" ng-click="makeActive('year')">year</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, here is the hint for you. [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Txo7RdTkTSEs9xzM06Sh?p=preview)

```
<div class="wrapper col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <a title="week? category"  class="tag" ng-class="{selected:selectedType == 'week'}" ng-click="makeActive('week')">week
        <select ng-show="selectedType == 'week'">
          <option>week 1</option>
          <option>week 2</option>
          <option>week 3</option>
        </select>
        </a>
        <a title="week? category"  class="tag" ng-class="{selected:selectedType == 'month'}" ng-click="makeActive('month')">month
        <select ng-show="selectedType == 'month'">
          <option>month 1</option>
          <option>month 2</option>
          <option>month 3</option>
        </select>
        </a>
        <a title="week? category"  class="tag" ng-class="{selected:selectedType == 'year'}" ng-click="makeActive('year')">year
        <select ng-show="selectedType == 'year'">
          <option>year 1</option>
          <option>year 2</option>
          <option>year 3</option>
        </select>
        </a>
      </div>
```